# View link - no sign-in required

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions

I have changed my settings for sharing the file as View link - no sign-in required.  But when I click on the drop down to share it still doesn't show the changes I made. [image]

Also, I would love for them to be able to download the file automatically when clicking on the link so that it can be viewed on their end.  How would I do that?  I read somewhere you can change something in the link, but my link is like this example:
https://careficient.sharepoint.com/:p:/g/Eb1nYPOAd1xFp9Wr5Mnr14AB4upeJ-WYceZqoa7xnGHTws